# Inconsistency between GeoLite2 City and GeoLite2 Country

Tags: geoip, maxmind

We started using the GeoLite2 Country DB and saw some very strange results. Looking closely it appeared that the DB itself had incorrect data. Looking more closely I saw that for the same IP the GeoLite2 Country and GeoLite2 City gave different results.

(I may also be reading this wrong so any advice on that most welcome!)

The IP in question is 46.251.120.133

Maxmind – country 
- Doesn't have 46.251.120.0
- It does have 46.251.0.0 which is found as location 719819 (Hungary) which is incorrect.

Maxmind - city 
- Has 46.251.120.0 which is found as location 146268 (Nicosia, Cyprus) which is, correct.

To be specific, we're using the csv files found here:
http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/

Really hoping I'm reading something wrong in the db...

Thanks!

Comment: I get Cyprus for both the GeoLite2 City and Country databases with the IP address `46.251.120.0`. Are you sure you have the latest database for each?

Comment: Hi oschwald, thanks for the reply. I'm downloading the countries DB (csv) from here http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/ and in the blocks file find 46.251.0.0 (.120.0 doesn't exist) and then lookup the location ID (719819) in the locations csv. This gives us Hungary. Is there something wrong with this logic? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

::46.251.120.0 is part of the ::ffff:46.251.96.0/115 network, which is mapped to 146669. 146669 is the blocks record for Cyrus.